# Как отправить на бекенд formdata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

У меня есть вот такая функция, которая записывает данные в formdata и затем вызывает функцию в store

```
const handleClick = (redButton) => {
        const shown = redButton === "confirm" ? "red" : "confirm"
        setRedButton(shown)
        if (redButton === 'red') {

            const formdata = new FormData()
            formdata.append('email', store.user.email)
            formdata.append('name', name)
            formdata.append('surname', surname)
            formdata.append('dob', dob)
            formdata.append('city', city)
            formdata.append('username', username)
            formdata.append('aboutMe', aboutM)
            formdata.append('img', ava)
            formdata.forEach((value, key) => {
                console.log(key, value);
            });
            store.saveData(formdata)
        }
```

Здесь отрабатывает store:

```
async saveData(formdata: any) {
        try {
            const response = await AuthService.saveData(formdata)
            console.log(response)
            this.setUser(response.data.user)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.response?.data?.message)
        }
    }
```

А здесь данные отправляются на бекенд

```
 static async saveData(formdata: any): Promise<AxiosResponse<AuthResponse>> {
        return $api.post<AuthResponse>('/user/save', { formdata })
    }
```

Вот здесь на бекенде она принимает данные и записывает в бд

```
async saveData(req, res, next) {
        try {

            if (req.files) {
                const { email, name, surname, city, dob, username, aboutMe } = req.body
                const { img } = req.files
                const userData = await userService.saveData(email, name, surname, city, dob, username, aboutMe, img)
                res.cookie('refreshToken', userData.refreshToken, { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true })
                return res.json({ message: 'workimg' })
            } else {
                const { email, name, surname, city, dob, username, aboutMe } = req.body
                const userData = await userService.saveData(email, name, surname, city, dob, username, aboutMe)
                res.cookie('refreshToken', userData.refreshToken, { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true })
                return res.json(userData)
            }


        } catch (e) {
            next(e)
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что данные не доходят с клиента, но если отправить formdata через postman, то все отрабатывает корректно, на моменте когда store принимает formdata, то данные находятся в formdata, но потом они теряются
Заранее спасибо!!!

UPD
Ошибка, которую выдает сервер:
[image: Ошибка, которую выдает сервер:]

upd

Вот, что выдает мне postman, тоже самое должно приходить с клиента
[image: ответ postman]

Это ошибка, которую выдает сервер, как я понял данные не доходят до сервера вообще

```
Error: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1743:13)    
    at C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1734:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1732:35)   
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2075:19)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.selectQuery (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:988:28)        
    at PostgresQueryInterface.select (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:59)
    at user.findAll (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1140:47)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async user.findOne (C:\Users\Миша\Desktop\основы не менять — копия\----------------\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1240:12)
```

Comment: Сам запрос то с клиента уходит? Какие заголовки стоят в постмане и у вас?

Comment: Запрос с клиента уходит, но сервер возвращает ошибку. Если отправить с постмена, то вернет две модели: одну с jwt токенами, а другую с моделью пользователя и соответственно с данными, все работает корректно. Но когда отправляю с клиента, то функция не  отрабатывает. Сначала я отправлял на сервер не formdata, а сами переменные и все работало также корректно,, но мне нужно было еще отправлять изображение поэтому пришлось сделать через formdata и как итог не работает

Comment: Какую ошибку получаете? Добавьте это к вопросу

Comment: какие логи сервера? В каком конкретно месте он падает? Какие заголовки отправляются в POSTMAN и какие при запросе из браузера?

Comment: Эту ошибку вам браузер выдал. Что по логам сервера?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас в переменной email ничего нет, точнее undifened, либо с клиента этот параметр не передавался, т.к. там он undefined. Проверяйте, что отправилось с клиента и какие данные получаются в req.body

Comment: Смотрите что у Вас находится в `formdata.append('email', store.user.email)`, т.е. в `store.user`. Выглядит так, что у `user` поле/свойство `email` недоступно/отсутствует.

Comment: данные в formdata нормально записываются, но до сервера не доходят

Comment: Как ты проверил что они "нормально записываются"? Что показывается в payload на вкладке network для твоего запроса?

Comment: Потому что я в логи данные из формы вывожу, там все есть